# Can AWS Lambda function be written in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The rest of the code is in JavaScript, so I would like to write AWS Lambda functions in JavaScript too. However I'm not able find documentation of this. Most of the material deals in Java, node.js, C# or Python.

Comment: node.js is javascript

Comment: You can write Lambda functions using Node.js.

Comment: node.js is not a language or a special dialect of JavaScript - it's just a thingamabob that runs normal JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is a Javascript on the server. Follow the Node.js documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html